# TFIDF vector into LSTM model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, tf-idf

I am trying to feed my TFIDF vector into an LSTM model.
`TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2), use_idf=True, analyzer='word', max_features = 5000)`

Here's the Vector shapes
`train_vector.shape` = (22895, 5000)
`test_vector.shape` = (5724, 5000)

I am defining a model like below:

```
model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.LSTM(64, input_shape=(5000, 1), activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))

model.add(layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Other Parameters

```
model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
model.fit(train_vector, y_train, validation_data=(test_vector, y_test), epochs=10, batch_size=1024)
```

Tensorflow is being used here.

I am getting this error

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_2 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (None, 5000)

I am trying to reshape the arrays, but the errors are still showing. I know LSTM needs 3D array. So how can I shape my arrays in a way that can be fed into LSTM???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new dimension to your training and test data, you can try:

```
train_vector = train_vector[..., None] # or tf.newaxis instead of None
test_vector = test_vector[..., None] # or tf.newaxis instead of None
```

or

```
train_vector = tf.expand_dims(train_vector, axis=-1)
test_vector = tf.expand_dims(test_vector, axis=-1)
```

Also, note that if you have one node in your output layer and you are using a sigmoid activation function, you usually combine it with the `binary_crossentropy` loss function instead of `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`, which is usually used for more than 2 classes.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Also I did stumble upon a problem with Sparse Categorical. Ended up using binary crossentropy. Accuracy is low but fortunately, very close for training and validation. But I am looking to improve this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe try using `1D` CNNs